# Knockout foreach accessing 2D json array

Tags: arrays, json, knockout.js, foreach

Hope someone can help me out with this:

I'm working with knockout and have the following json array:

[[174302,"BUSINESS - APPLICATION TO CONDUCT A BUSINESS FROM HOME.pdf",".pdf","DK89639"],[120183,"Glovent-Brochure.pdf",".pdf","DK472894"]]

inside my "consumerData" variable.

As you can see there are 2 arrays with 4 elements inside each.

Here is how I am trying to access it:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: consumerData" style="margin-bottom:100px;">                 
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<p style="font-size:larger; margin-bottom:5px;"><a data-bind="attr: { href: 'http://someaddress/address/'+consumerData[0]+''+consumerData[2]+'?key='+consumerData[3]+'' }"><div data-bind="text: consumerData[1]"></div></a></p>
</td></tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

So this is looping twice which is correct but how do I access my data inside each array?

PLease help!

Thanks!

Regards
Francois

Comment: I'd remove that IP address from your code unless you like unexpected visitors

Comment: thanks have done so!

Comment: I updated the fiddle as well, wasn't thinking when I put it together

Comment: yes wanted to ask, thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access unnamed data within a loop by accessing the `$data` object (instead of `consumerData` again), which represents the current context

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5c6y46bo/

Also, you don't need to put a div inside your link to hold the text of the current object, just put the `text` binding within the `<a>` element's binding alongside the `attr` binding.

Comment: Thanks!! You are just awesome :)

Comment: Hi dfperry, I hope you can help on this. I'm trying to bind the $data[0] inside a onclick which is inside the foreach loop. It looks like it doesn't work (I'm using InAppBrowser for this). For example like this: <a style="text-decoration:none;" data-bind="attr: { href: 'http://domain:8080/dsservlet/'+$data[0]+'.png?key=DK188961' }, text: $data[1]" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://domain:8080/dsservlet/'+$data[0]+'.png?key=DK188961', '_blank', 'location=yes'); return false;"></a>

Comment: If you want to bind to an individual field, it must be an observable too